# WebMethod: Turn off XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I built an ASP.NET Web Service Application (.NET 3.5) with a simple WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetToken()
    {
       return "Hello";
    }
```

The response looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <string xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/">Hello</string>
```

This works fine. However, one of my customers can't deal with the XML-Wrapper around the result string. Is there a way to turn off the XML and just return the pure string "Hello" (without quotation marks of course ;-)).?

Comment: In which way, GetToken() method is invoked? From javascript or others way?

Comment: Afaik, my customer is using PHP and calls my webmethod per GET, e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/WebServiceApp.asmx/GetToken

Comment: But just to be clear: I am looking for a solution that changes my side ...can't ask my customer to change his code. I was just hoping for a little trick to turn off XML on my side (web.config setting or something).

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx

Basically, to get the string back you'd have to return JSON result which, in turn, can Be accomplished either by issuing a POST from your PHP client or by adding

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
```

to your web method.

Also, make sure you follow the steps outlined here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services
to create AJAX-enabled service in the first place. For example, you need to add

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

attribute to your class to allow it to behave like an AJAX service...

Comment: Hello Dmitry, thanks so much for your suggestions. But I still couldn't achieve an XML free response.

I added [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] on top of my webservice class (which is of type System.Web.Services.WebService) and I added [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] on top of my web method. 

Calling my webservice with http://www.mywebsite.com/WebServiceApp.asmx/GetToken still returns the original response (including xml). :-( Am I missing something?

Comment: Ingmar, you should also check your web.config handlers: 
<httpHandlers>
     <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
     <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false"
          type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,
          System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
          PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpHandlers>

Comment: Hello Dmitry, actually, I already did this. But I'm still retrieving XML. But maybe I just misinterpret the results of what I'm doing. In order to simulate a GET request I just enter http://localhost:50733/WebServiceApp.asmx/GetToken in the address field of my browser. Isn't this a GET request? Thanks so much for your help again!